# Pandas - Error in if function when creating a new column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column `lastseason`type object (no NULL or NaN) in the df `draft`. I would like to create a new column `Age_retired` based on the comparison of the last 2 digits of `lastseason` to 50.

Here is the last season column

```
0       1993-94
1       1990-91
2       1993-94
3       1997-98
Name: lastseason, dtype: object
```

Extract the last 2 digit and convert to numeric

```
print pd.to_numeric(draft['lastseason'].astype('str').str[-2:],errors='coerce')
0       94
1       91
2       94
3       98
Name: lastseason, dtype: int64
```

Create column `Age_retired`

```
if pd.to_numeric(draft['lastseason'].astype('str').str[-2:],errors='coerce') <50:
 draft['Age_retired'] = 2000 + pd.to_numeric(draft['lastseason'].astype('str').str[-2:],errors='coerce')
else:
 draft['Age_retired'] = 1900 + pd.to_numeric(draft['lastseason'].astype('str').str[-2:],errors='coerce')
```

I got the error with the `if` line: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I am thinking that my `if-else` structure is not applied to columns with many values. Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the if-else construct won't be evaluated element-wise. However, this is solved easily using the series `.map` method which applies a function elementwise. First you define the function, then you map it. You can simply assign the result of the mapping to `draft['age_retired']` to create the new column.

```
In [10]: def add_age_retired(x):
             if x < 50:
                 return 2000 + x
             else:
                 return 1900 + x


In [11]: pd.to_numeric(draft['lastseason'].astype('str').str[-2:],errors='coerce').map(add_age_retired)
Out[11]: 
0    1994
1    1991
2    1994
3    1998
Name: lastseason, dtype: int64

In [12]: draft['Age_retired'] = pd.to_numeric(draft['lastseason'].astype('str').str[-2:],errors='coerce').map(add_age_retired)

In [13]: draft
Out[13]: 
  lastseason  Age_retired
0    1993-94         1994
1    1990-91         1991
2    1993-94         1994
3    1997-98         1998
```

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. Just curious, is there anyway to do the same thing without defining a new function?

Comment: @Square9627 You can use a lambda function if you don't want to define a new one:

`...map(lambda x: 2000 + x if < 50 else 1900 + x)`